# Recursing the file system with Powershell

Tags: powershell, nsis

Anyone happen to have a sample script for recursing a given directory in a filesystem with Powershell? Ultimately what I'm wanting to do is create a script that will generate NSIS file lists for me given a directory. Something very similar to what was done [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/duffblog/2006/12/dynamic_file_list_with_nsis.html) with a BASH script.

Comment: Is my answer sufficient?  if so please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [halr9000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101783/recursing-the-file-system-with-powershell#106413) demonstrated, you can use the `-recurse` switch parameter of the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to retrieve all files and directories under a specified path.

It looks like the bash script you linked to in your question saves out the directories as well, so here is a simple function to return both the files and directories in a single result object:

```
function Get-InstallFiles {
  param( [string]$path )

  $allItems = Get-ChildItem -path $path -recurse
  $directories = $allItems | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % { $_.FullName }
  $installFiles = $allItems | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | % { $_.FullName }
  $uninstallFiles = $installFiles[-1..-$installFiles.Length]

  $result = New-Object PSObject
  $result | Add-Member NoteProperty Directories $directories
  $result | Add-Member NoteProperty InstallFiles $installFiles
  $result | Add-Member NoteProperty UninstallFiles $uninstallFiles
  return $result
}
```

Here is how you could use it to create the same install/uninstall text files from halr9000's example, including uninstall directories:

```
$files = Get-InstallFiles 'C:\some\directory'
$files.InstallFiles | Set-Content 'installfiles.txt'
$files.UninstallFiles + $files.Directories | Set-Content 'uninstallfiles.txt'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a "paraphrase" port of that bash script.

```
$path = "c:\path\to\program"
$installFiles = "installfiles_list.txt"
$uninstFiles = "uninstfiles_list.txt"
$files = get-childitem -path $path -recurse | where-object { ! $_.psIsContainer } # won't include dirs
$filepath = $files | foreach-object { $_.FullName }
$filepath | set-content $installFiles -encoding ASCII
$filepath[($filepath.length-1)..0] | set-content $uninstFiles -encoding ASCII
```